# WordPress internationalization + domains

Tags: plugins, multisite, domain

Hello Dear WordPress'ers,

I want to have a website on WordPress engine running with other languages too.

I want to have a website + domains, for example like that:

```
myblog.com - main
myblog.de - translated to German
myblog.se - translated to Swedish
myblog.jp - translated to Japanese
```

Is it possible to run multiple websites (translated) like that with one WordPress + translations?
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use multisite when it's about running multiple websites with one installation. You can also use plugins such as [MLS](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/) to links content. That could be useful to add links to other versions of your posts.

To me, multisite + MLS is better regarding perfomance if you compare this with solution such as WPML and qTranslate but it depends on what you want to do. If you need to translate medias, theme and plugins so you have a lot of things to translate the plugin WPML is also a good and handy solution.